# Check if enumeration contains multiple elements without throwing exception?

Tags: c#, linq, enumeration

I want to check if an enumeration contains 0, 1 or 1+ elements. I want to avoid the overhead of enumerating the entire sequence, thus want to avoid `Count()`.

I know Linq query `SingleOrDefault()` could be used for this purpose, but instead adds cumbersome exception handling in the 1+ case.

Any way to do it without `Count()` and without exception handling?

Comment: *Don't* use Single then, use `First`

Comment: You can just use `Count`

Comment: You ask if it contains *multiple* elements and you complain that `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` will throw an exception. The odd thing is that these two methods, though throwing exceptions, *doesn't do what you say you want to do*. Can you clarify what the question really is? Do you want to get the first element, check if it contains 1 element, at least 2?

Comment: Sorry. Added clarification about avodiing Count because it will enumerate the entire sequence.

Comment: I want to check if the enumeration contains 0, 1 or 1+ elements without using Count (to avoid the overhead of enumerating the entire sequence). Will clarify question text.

Comment: Do you want to obtain these 3 results *at the same time* without enumerating even the start of the collection more than once? Also, do you want the first item as a value if it exists? I'm just trying to avoid posting an answer only to have you go "Yes, but then how do I ..." immediately.

Comment: You can "classify" the contents of the collection by doing: `collection.Take(2).Count()` which will return 0, 1 or 2 (2 thus means 1+ elements). Would that be enough?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Yes, Take(2).Count() would be alright. I will use the result to choose code path below, and in the 1+ branch will enumerate the entire sequence or (in some cases) throw an exception with custom message text. With SingleOrDefault I would need to catch and rethrow to insert my specific message, which seems overly complex.

Comment: Note that this code would enumerate over the start of the collection, and your following enumeration would enumerate it again. If you need/want to avoid that, having 1 enumeration **in total**, then the code needs to be specifically written to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach to see if the sequence has more than one element is to use `Take` and `Count`, like this:

```
if (mySequence.Take(2).Count() == 2) {
    ... // Sequence has at least two elements
}
```

`Take(2)` limits counting to at most two, so using `Count()` is not as expensive as in `mySequence.Count() > 1`.

If you need to grab the first element, store the result of `Take` in a list to avoid iterating the sequence again.

Answer (score 2):

```
.ElementatOrdefault(1) != null
```

Comment: Nice, but I think Take(n).Count() is a bit clearer, with no significant difference in enumeration handling/overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use skip and any.

```
list.Skip(n).Any();
```

Comment: Nice, but I think Take(n).Count() is a bit clearer, with no significant difference in enumeration handling/overhead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the first element that matches some criteria, you should use [First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx) or [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx), not [Single](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325(v=vs.110).aspx)